Adding UnitTest project to solution: The specified RuntimeIdentifier is not recognized
I set up a WinUI 3 project for .NET 8.0 a few weeks ago.
In the beginning I encountered a problem that has been described on StackOverflow before here.
Searching for the error code (NETSDK1083) also lead me to a microsoft page where the error was explained here.
After reading through these articles and adjusting the csproj file of my project, removing the "10" from the RIDs, the project started successfully and I did not hear of this error until now.
Today I added a UnitTest project via MSTestv2 and also in a different attempt with NUnit.
Both lead to the same problem:
When adding the main-project as a reference in the UnitTest project, I again run into a lot of the earlier described errors with the same error code.
The error codes when adding a UnitTest project
All of the errors I received today, link to line 90 in the file C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.204\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets
Here the tag  has the property RuntimeIdentifier inside, which reads from a variable named "RuntimeIdentifier". As this file is supposed to stay unmodified, and I tried to hardcode a win-x64 into the property, which still did not work, I'm afraid that this is not the root cause of the problem.
Another attempt was to look for the csproj file of the newly added test project, to see if there are any mentions of RuntimeIdentifiers that still have the distro-specific RID (e.g. win10-x64 instead of win-x64). But no, even a fulltext search over the whole solution did not reveal any mention of that.
Can anyone help me here? I definitely need Unit Tests for my project and I can not imagine that this error is specific to my Windows installation.
Edit:
Today this warning showed up (was not displayed before)
Warnings regarding RID

Can you post the XML code of your test project? Of remove lines that you don't want to share.

@AndrewKeepCoding hey Andrew, do you mean the csproj file? https://pastebin.com/V61ySJe8

Your test project seems to be for a basic .NET project, not for a WinUI 3 app project.
It might be still in preview but I can add unit test projects for WinUI 3 apps on Visual Studio 2022 Preview:

And my unit test project looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFramework>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <RootNamespace>SampleAppTests</RootNamespace>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
    <Platforms>x86;x64;ARM64</Platforms>
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)')) &gt;= 8">win-x86;win-x64;win-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> 
    <RuntimeIdentifiers Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkVersion('$(TargetFramework)')) &lt; 8">win10-x86;win10-x64;win10-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
    <PublishProfile>win-$(Platform).pubxml</PublishProfile>
    <UseWinUI>true</UseWinUI>
    <EnableMsixTooling>true</EnableMsixTooling>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Page Remove="UnitTestApp.xaml" />
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="UnitTestApp.xaml" />
    <ProjectCapability Include="TestContainer" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Assets\SplashScreen.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\LockScreenLogo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\StoreLogo.png" />
    <Content Include="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Windows.SDK.BuildTools" Version="10.0.22621.756" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsAppSDK" Version="1.5.240428000" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="3.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.TestPlatform.TestHost" Version="17.7.2">
      <ExcludeAssets>build</ExcludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <Manifest Include="$(ApplicationManifest)" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "Msix" ProjectCapability here allows the Single-project MSIX Packaging
    Tools extension to be activated for this project even if the Windows App SDK Nuget
    package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(DisableMsixProjectCapabilityAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <ProjectCapability Include="Msix" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SampleApp\SampleApp.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- 
    Defining the "HasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject" property here allows the Solution 
    Explorer "Package and Publish" context menu entry to be enabled for this project even if 
    the Windows App SDK Nuget package has not yet been restored.
  -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(DisableHasPackageAndPublishMenuAddedByProject)'!='true' and '$(EnableMsixTooling)'=='true'">
    <HasPackageAndPublishMenu>true</HasPackageAndPublishMenu>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>


Thank you. This works. After downloading the newest preview version I can now see the projects for winui unit tests being available. My problem now is that I still have an error that occurs when trying to reference a class from my regular project inside the test projekt. It references aka.ms/netsdk1150. I will look further into this but would be interested if you also got this error?

Adding this line into the testproject's csproj file, the tests were also able to access classes from the main project file (aka.ms/netsdk1150):false
